# Is the set of points $x$ with $\Vert \mathrm{grad} f(x)\Vert < \varepsilon$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function and $\mathrm{grad}f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is its gradient. For $\varepsilon>0$, is the set $$
\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n \, \mid \, \Vert \mathrm{grad} f(x)\Vert < \varepsilon\}$$
convex?

When $n=1$, this is true since $\mathrm{grad} f(x)=f'(x)$ is an increasing function which implies that the set in question must be an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is not true. Consider the convex function
$$
f(x,y) := \frac14 (x^4 + y^4) - x - y.$$
Then
$$
\nabla f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} x^3 -1 \\ y^3 - 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Consequently,
$$
\|\nabla f(1,0)\| = \|\nabla f(0,1)\| = 1,$$
but for the midpoint we have
$$
\|\nabla f(1/2, 1/2)\| \approx 1.23,$$
which is bigger.

Here are some contour lines of $\|\nabla f(\cdot)\|$:

[image: click]